# Why Won't These Jest Mocks Reset?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, redux, jestjs

I have test code that is effecting other tests and causing them to fail. When I run test cases in isolation everything passes, but when I run the entire suit there are many failures. If you look at both tests below you can see I override a mocked module within the test to cause an exception to be thrown.

```
HttpService.post = jest.fn(() => {
   return Promise.reject({ payload: 'rejected' });
});
```

after this line has been run, all tests that need the original `HttpService.post` mock fail because they aren't reset. How can I properly restore my mock to the imported mock after this test? I have tried `jest.resetMock` in a beforeEach and about every jest method like it but nothing has worked. I know the answer is probably straight forward but I am confused with all of the differences I read about online around how code is imported (es6 import, commonJs). Thanks!

```
import HttpService from '../../services/httpService';
import handleErrors from '../../utilities/handleErrors';

jest.mock('../../services/httpService');
jest.mock('../../utilities/handleErrors');

describe('async actions', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({});
  });

  describe('some describe that wraps both tests', () => {

    describe('a describe that wraps just the first test', () => {
      test(`creates ${constants.actions.REQUEST_SAVE_NOTE_FAILURE}`, () => {
        HttpService.post = jest.fn(() => {
          return Promise.reject({ payload: 'rejected' });
        });
        const expectedActions = [
          { type: constants.actions.REQUEST_SAVE_NOTE },
          { type: constants.actions.REQUEST_SAVE_NOTE_FAILURE, data: { payload: 'rejected' } },
        ];
        return store.dispatch(actions.saveNote({
          id: 1,
          note: 'note',
        })).then(() => {
          expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        });
      });
    });

    describe('a describe that wraps just the second test', () => {
      test(`creates ${constants.actions.REQUEST_SAVE_NOTE}
        and ${constants.actions.RECEIVE_SAVE_NOTE}`, () => {
        params = {
          body: {
            prospects: [1],
            note: 'note',
          },
        };
        const expectedActions = [
          { type: constants.actions.REQUEST_SAVE_NOTE },
          { type: constants.actions.RECEIVE_SAVE_NOTE, data: { payload: 'payload' } },
        ];

        return store.dispatch(actions.saveNote({
          id: 1,
          note: 'note',
        })).then(() => {
          expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
          expect(HttpService.post).toBeCalledWith({ ...params, url: '/api/prospect/add-note' });
        });
      });
    });

  })

});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you import a module that is an object you need to mock every exported function independently:

```
import HttpService from '../../services/httpService';
jest.mock('../../services/httpService', ()=>({
  post: jest.fn()
});
```

later on you can set the the behaviour of the mock like this

```
HttpService.post.mockImplementation(()=>Promise.reject({ payload: 'rejected' }))
```

and reset

```
HttpService.post.mockReset()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far, this is not yet working. I do have HttpService.post mocked as you have described as a manual mock in __mocks__ folder. The mock still won't set back to the implementation I provided. Do you have code that works like this with import syntax i've used? Thanks! @andreas

Comment: what do you get when logging `HttpService.post`

Comment: if I log ```HttpService.post``` it says its a jest mock before and after being reset, but if invoke and log ```HttpService.post()``` before its reset it says ```Promise { <rejected> { payload: 'rejected' } }``` and after its reset ```undefined``` it's not setting back to the implementation from the mocks folder, know how to fix it?

Comment: maybe `mockRestore()` is what you looking for then

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. It turns out that this https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/5720 was the issue, and upgrading Jest to at least version 23.0.0 fixed the problem. As of this writing, 23.6 is the latest stable version of Jest.

In my case, `mockRejectedValueOnce` was appearing to not be reset, because when I commented out `mockRejectedValueOnce` methods on prior tests, my later test (the test in question) worked again. So the reset method was not being effective.

Answer (score 2):

IF you are wanting to mock a module (using a mock factory) for some tests within a file, but unmock it for others - this works for me:

```
describe("some tests", () => {
  let subject;

  describe("with mocks", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      jest.isolateModules(() => {
        jest.doMock("some-lib", () => ({ someFn: jest.fn() })); // doMock isnt hoisted with babel
        subject = require('./module-that-imports-some-lib');
      });
    });

    // ... tests when some-lib is mocked
  });

  describe("without mocks - restoring mocked modules", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      jest.isolateModules(() => {
        jest.unmock("some-lib");
        subject = require('./module-that-imports-some-lib');
      });
    });

    // ... tests when some-lib is NOT mocked

  });
});
```